# Failed to mail or browse IOException

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, desktop, error-code

I'm trying to use the following code to open a URI from within the program. I could easily display the URL to the user and encourage them to paste it into the browser, but I want the operation to be less effort.

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;

URI uri = null;
try {
    uri = new URI(ProgramName.currentProject.saveFilePath + "/file.html");
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
    try {
        desktop.browse(uri);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    //attempt workaround
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to mail or browse /Users/myname/ProgramName/SaveFiles/Guillotine/file.html. Error code: -10814
```

But I don't know why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, found the answer.

I thought I could create a URI with just the file path, failing to realise I had to add `file:///` to the front of the path before it would work.

Leaving this up in the hopes that someone else makes the same obvious mistake.

Comment: You could also use `file.toURI()`, possibly checking first that the file does actually exist.